# Exporting a CDF to HTML

Tags: export, cdf-format, html

I'm using *Mathematica for Students* on a Mac. How do I export a CDF document to HTML?  According to the Wolfram website I should click on `File > Deploy > Export as HTML`. But I do not see the `Deploy` contextual menu item in my File menu. Has it been moved on the Mac version?

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: Mac OS X 10.7; Mathematica 8

Comment: Hmm, didn't read far enough, I see. On my machine (OS X 10.6.8 - MMA v.8), `Deploy` is the fifth item from the bottom. It is right above `Install` and the 3 printing commands.

Comment: @rcollyer What licence do you have? I'm using Mathematica Home Edition v. 8.0.4 for OS X, and there is no menu item called Deploy in my version either.

Comment: @Heike I'm running the Student Edition v8.0.4.

Comment: @Heike Are you sure you have the latest version? I logged into Wolfram Portal and downloaded the latest updates, then rechecked to make sure I was current.

Answer (score 12):

You do not really need a tool to depoly your CDF to HTML. It is very simple to do by hand. Here is what I do

1. open your text editor and create a file called index.htm

   ```
   <HTML>    
   <BODY >
   This is my CDF

   <p>

   <script src="http://www.wolfram.com/cdf-player/plugin/v1.0/cdfplugin.js"
   type="text/javascript"></script><script type="text/javascript">// 
   <![CDATA[
   var cdf = new cdf_plugin();
   cdf.addCDFObject("source", "source.cdf",840,1435);
   // ]]></script>

   <P>
   </BODY>
   </HTML>
   ```
2. From Mathematica, save your notebook as `source.cdf` (using SAVE AS->CDF). Save it to the same folder your created the above index.htm file to. So now your folder have 2 files in it: `source.cdf` and `index.htm`
3. use your ftp program and upload these 2 files to your web site tree where you want to put them.
4. that is all. Click on the index.htm and will run the CDF.

ps. If you want to just show the Manipulate part in your CDF and not the code around it, then before doing SAVE AS, select the code cells and do `CELL->CELL properties->` and un check the open option so that the cell becomes closed.

So that the code cells (or any other cell you choose to close) are not open for view. This way, when someone sees your CDF, they only see the GUI part (i.e. the manipulate) and not any other cell you did not want them to see).

Comment: Hi, I don`t understand what am I supposed to replace your "This is my CDF" by. Is it the path to the file ?

Comment: Did not work for me! Any updates to your wonderful answer over the years? I use version 12.0

Comment: @Dean  CDF's no longer work in HTML. This has been the case for may be 2-3 years.  All browsers I know about have stopped supporting these types of plugins.  Only way to run CDF's now is to download it to your computer and use the CDF player.

Comment: @Nasser, many thanks for this important information. I have got CDF player, thank you for your suggestion. However, are there other means of web deployment for my mathematica code? I have a project that would not be nice if only CDF player is to be used,

Comment: @Dean  I have not kept up with cloud activity with WRI. But you could try getting a cloud account at Wolfram. Check [https://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/online/](https://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/online/). You could also ask about this as separate question, as I really know very little about it. I do all my programing on the PC directly using Mathematica and Maple these days. Do not use any cloud/internet things.

Answer (score 10):

The deploy functionality was introduced in Mathematica 8.0.4. To my knowledge, it is not available in 8.0.1.0, see the [changelog](http://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/quick-revision-history.html).

Comment: Okay I have 8.0.0.0 installed. I will update my software. Thanks!